# Using Vue Components with ASP MVC .NET, @HTML.Partial("Component.cshtml")?

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, npm, webpack, vue.js

Since I can't figure out how to set up Visual Studio to use Webpack, NPM, etc, so I can include Single File Components with Import, I was looking for a simple way to use my components without this technology.

Here is my solution...
http://sob-vuejs.blogspot.com/2017/11/a-little-trick-to-create-single-file.html

I have been programming using .NET since the beginning, and have created several very successful companies, so I'm not complaining, however, I have had my head in the sand and have not paid much attention to the Javascript world. So, if anyone can help me out with a simple step by step guide to set up Visual Studio, NPM, Webpack, Vue, and all the other things I would need I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Not sure about ASP.NET MVC (classic) but with ASP.NET Core, there’s a template that includes a basic Vue setup. Maybe you can use that to transfer it to your application (although it won’t work as nice as with ASP.NET Core) – http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1383/modern-web-dev-aspnet-core-webpack-vuejs

Comment: Can you name the file `.vue` instead of `.cshtml` and still render the partial?